# Need to exit a function if var is empty and make ajax display an error PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Okay, so I have an AJAX function that sends data to the .php file, which processes it (simple as that):

```
$(document).on('click','#submit',function () {
    var title = $('#title_submit').val();
    var content = $('#content_submit').val();
    var image = $('#image_url').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../parts/add.php",
        data: {
            title: title,
            content: content,
            image: image
        },
        success: function (data) {
            redirect(); //a function that redirects to the main page
        }
    });
});
```

The content passes fine, and the function processes it. So, if there is no image ("image_url" field is empty) it simply ignores it and just adds the title and the content... But if there is an image it checks it's type (`switch ($info) { case 'image/jpg':...`) if none of them match:

```
default:
$new_name = "";
break;
}
```

**and here's the hard part (for me):**

```
if ($new_name == "") {
...//stop from executing and say "That ain't no image you be sendin'"; 
} else { //continue with adding an image to the folder and than creating a thumbnail of it...
```

I tried `die()` but if I entered something like "11111111111111111111111" into the Image URL input it entered "11111111111111111111111" into the database and outputed it instead of the image.

Comment: it should be if ($new_name == "") or if ($new_name === "")

Comment: use if(empty($new_name)) you assign variable instead of checking it

Comment: now that that's fixed, how do I stop the whole thing from executing and give out an error on the same page (using AJAX)?

Answer (score 1):

You are checking wrong way, its like assigning empty string to $name use == operator to check against empty string

```
if ($new_name == "") {
```

Comment: damn, such a stupid mistake :) but anyway, I corrected, but it still outputs text if I enter an unexisting url or simply text

Comment: Wait are you trying to upload image using this?

Comment: It won't work like this with ajax. You need to looks for some third party plugins that support image upload using ajax